# CocoaPods Error to install/search pods

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to use some pods in my project. But the terminal results in that:

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `Mantle`.
```

So, I tryed to search the pod or others and for any pod that I have tryed, the result is:

```
$ pod search Mantle
[!] Unable to find a pod with name matching `Mantle'

$ pod search LBBlurredImage
[!] Unable to find a pod with name matching `LBBlurredImage'
```

What is wrong?! The https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs have all pods....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This just happened to me as well. Somehow the CocoaPods repo got borked. This fixed my situation:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
pod setup
pod install
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Also - before I did this I did a `sudo gem install cocoapods` to reinstall the newest cocoapods.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to run `pod setup`

Edit:

In theory if you're getting an error about the master repo you could add it manually run:

```
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

Comment: humm....and the result of pod setup was:

Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] The `master` repo is not a git repo.

WTF!?

Comment: Same thing happened to me just now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it worked for me

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying these commands and couldn't understand what was happening because there were no logs printed to screen indicating the progress.

Heads up, this is a time taking install, so run the command, sit back and relax :)

Clean up directory

`$ rm -rf ~/.cocoapods`

So add verbose at the end of command beginning with

`$ sudo gem install cocoapods --verbose`

There are lot of redirects happening here which takes additional time.

```
GET https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.1.3.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.1.3.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.2.0.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.2.0.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.1.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.1.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.2.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.2.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.3.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.3.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.4.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.4.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.5.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/thread_safe-0.3.5.gemspec.rz
200 OK
Installing gem cocoapods-0.39.0
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/cache/clean.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/cache/list.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/cache.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/inter_process_communication.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/lib.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/list.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/outdated.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/add.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/lint.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/list.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/remove.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/update.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/setup.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/cat.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/create.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/edit.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/which.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/request.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/response.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/abstract_external_source.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/downloader_source.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/podspec_source.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/gem_version.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/acknowledgements/markdown.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/acknowledgements/plist.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/acknowledgements.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/bridge_support.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/copy_resources_script.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/dummy_source.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/embed_frameworks_script.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/header.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/info_plist_file.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/module_map.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/prefix_header.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/umbrella_header.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig/aggregate_xcconfig.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig/pod_xcconfig.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig/xcconfig_helper.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/hooks_manager.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/analysis_result.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/locking_dependency_analyzer.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/sandbox_analyzer.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/specs_state.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspection_result.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/file_references_installer.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/migrator.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_preparer.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/podfile_validator.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/post_install_hooks_context.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/pre_install_hooks_context.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/source_provider_hooks_context.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/target_installer/aggregate_target_installer.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/target_installer/pod_target_installer.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/target_installer.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/open_uri.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/project.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver/lazy_specification.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/headers_store.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/path_list.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/pod_dir_cleaner.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/podspec_finder.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/sandbox.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/target/aggregate_target.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/target/pod_target.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/target.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/bin/pod
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/bin/sandbox-pod
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/README.md
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/LICENSE
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/CHANGELOG.md
/usr/local/bin/pod
/usr/local/bin/sandbox-pod
Successfully installed cocoapods-0.39.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.39.0
Parsing sources...
100% [93/93]  lib/cocoapods/validator.rb
1 gem installed
```

Then run 
`$ pod setup --verbose`

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo

Creating shallow clone of spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --depth=1
  Cloning into 'master'...
  Checking out files: 100% (70092/70092), done.
  $ /usr/bin/git checkout master
  Already on 'master'
  Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

CocoaPods 1.0.0.beta.3 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Setup completed
```

and after that 
`$  pod install --verbose`

```
  Preparing

Updating local specs repositories

Updating spec repo `master`
  $ /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only
  Already up-to-date.

CocoaPods 1.0.0.beta.3 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.


Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods`: (``)
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Vue`: (``)
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-VueTests`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  - AFNetworking
  - FBSDKCoreKit
  - FBSDKLoginKit
  - FBSDKMessengerShareKit
  - FBSDKShareKit
  - Facebook-iOS-SDK
  - LayerKit
  - Localytics
  - REMenu
  - Realm
  - SDWebImage
  - SSKeychain
  - libextobjc

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A AFNetworking
  A Bolts
  A FBSDKCoreKit
  A FBSDKLoginKit
  A FBSDKMessengerShareKit
  A FBSDKShareKit
  A Facebook-iOS-SDK
  A LayerKit
  A Localytics
  A REMenu
  A Realm
  A SDWebImage
  A SSKeychain
  A libextobjc

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing AFNetworking (2.6.0)
 > Git download
 > Git download
     $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git /var/folders/0t/dp8zzlyj58z5w00z21h5pcd00000gt/T/d20160206-31717-10giru1 --single-branch
     --depth 1 --branch 2.6.0 --recursive
     Cloning into '/var/folders/0t/dp8zzlyj58z5w00z21h5pcd00000gt/T/d20160206-31717-10giru1'...
     Note: checking out 'f28d4af6c47bad1192f87debcc76586e3a8a141a'.

     You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
     changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
     state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

     If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
     do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

       git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

  > Copying AFNetworking from `/Users/vinay/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/AFNetworking/2.6.0-79f7e` to `Pods/AFNetworking`
```