# Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or description matching `xxx`

Tags: cocoapods

pod search xxx and then output Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or description matching `xxx`

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21492886

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal

run `pod setup`

then run `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Cocoapods`

then `pod search {anything}` and it will work

Comment: Actually worked.  Can't believe it's so hard to get a basic feature like search up and going for Cocoapods.  Gee whiz.

Answer (score 0):

if you found deleting the cache dir didn't work, try this:
input the command below, one by one

`pod repo remove master`

`cd ~/.cocoapods/repos`(if not exist, mkdir -p ~/.cocoapods/repos)

`git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master`

`rm ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/search_index.json`

`pod search AFNetworking`