# Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or description matching `xxx`

Tags: ios, terminal, cocoapods

I also searched stackoverflow:

[Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or description matching `xxx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581352/unable-to-find-a-pod-with-name-author-summary-or-description-matching-xxx)

And I upvoted it, but seems there is no response to this type question, but it is real a issue here for cocoapods.

I run:

```
$ pod --version
```

It shows:

> 1.1.1

But I use pod search library:

```
$ pod search AFNetworking
```

It shows

> [!] Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or description matching `AFNetworking`
>
> [!] Skipping `Specs` because the podspec contains errors.

The snapshot:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

**Attempt**

I trid remove the `search_index.json` in terminal, but it did not work for me, it maybe helpful to others who has the similar problem.

```
$ sudo rm ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/search_index.json
```

or

```
$ rm ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/search_index.json
```

Some one can help ?

Comment: Hi if you just need to know what pod to use for AFNetwork for example, you can search [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org) for whatever framework you need.

Comment: @Dania, thanks for your comment, but my post is a real issue, I find many people run into this situation, but did not get a well-answer.

Answer (score 0):

check .zshrc  pager="What"
My pager is most,then change to "less"
Pod search is be ok